# Matching columns of two CSV files based on ID using Python instead of Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, import-csv

Hello I am looking for some help to do like an index match in excel i am very new to python but my data sets are far to large for excel now

I will dumb my question right down as much as possible cause the data contains alot of irrelevant information to this problem

CSV A (has 3 Basic columns)

```
ID, Age, FirstName
3,   18,   Lia
```

CSV B (has 3 columns)

```
ID, Score, LastName
3,    10,    Mia
```

CSV C (I want to create this using python; 4 columns - add LastName column from CSV B to CSV A)

```
ID, Age, FirstName, LastName 
3,   18,    Lia,       Mia
```

All I want to do is match the LastName from CSV B to the corresponding ID number in CSV A. And return this information in CSV C.

Any help is much appreciated I don't seem to be getting very far

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you read your input with pandas.read_csv() and then take a look on this function:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

your left and right key should be the ID

EDIT: I saw you dont want to have your score value in the result table. Therefore just drop the column after merging

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: thank you @ffm_nosoup Is there a way to do this using the csv module instead?

Comment: mhh i've never used the module sorry can't help on that